IR2104 Low side FET not switching problem
I have been trying to lay the half bridge circuit using IR2104 gate driver and IRF540N N-channel mosfets. I have been following the circuit shown in the datasheet:

Here is how pins are connected:

VCC - 12V (filter cap 10uF)
IN - 3.3V PWM (4ms period) from ESP32 through a 2.2k Resistor
SD - 12V
COM - GND
VB to VS - 150nF bootstrap Cap
HO - high side fet Gate through 10 Ohm resistor
VS - bridge point as in the diagram
LO - low side gate through 10 Ohm Resistor
Hi-side fet Drain - 12V
Lo-side fet Drain - Hi-Side Src
Lo-side fet src - GND

I don't have oscilloscope access so I tried probing the pins using a multimeter. The observation is that the high side gate pin shows a variable voltage (probably switching) but the low side fet gate pin continuously stays 0V (Not switching at all).
I have referred a similar problem mentioned here and a few more circuit diagrams including using diodes in parallel with gate drive resistors however nothing works for me.
I tried stimulating the circuit using Multi-Sim (can't simulate due to some convergence issue I couldn't fix) and Infineon-designer where I don't get any gate voltage at all.
I would really appreciate some guidance on this!

Test with a lower voltage (something as 24 V in place of 600V). Use a load (something as 10 Ohm). PWM with a lower period, ~ 250 us.

you can use an LED as an indicator if you don't have a scope.

What's the duty cycle of your PWM?  If you're going to continue working with power electronics you might want to strongly consider getting an oscilloscope.  Without one it's almost like driving a car blind.....

@Antonio51 my voltage is 12 V not 600V and my PWM period is 4ms

The bootstrap capacitor is probably too low (1-> 2 uF, 2500 Hz min) ... https://www.skyworksinc.com/tools/bootstrap-calculator

PWM at 250 Hz (4 ms) is really too low.
